# how do I clone a disk that is represented by a vmdk file?

Tags: centos, virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, xfs

I have VirtualBox installed on Windows 8.1.  I have created a CentOS 7 virtual machine that loads the contents of a detached hard drive that is connected to the PC via a SATA Wire.  The virtual machine in VirtualBox has its SATA controller set as `usb.vmdk`.  The actual `usb.vmdk` file is very small, but it loads a large disk partition.

**How do I clone the contents of that disk partition so that I can create a virtual machine in VirtualBox that has all the same data that is in the detached hard drive?**

Note that CentOS 7 uses the XFS file system.

Here is the code that created `usb.vmdk`:

```
cd %programfiles%\oracle\virtualbox

VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename "%USERPROFILE%"\desktop\usb.vmdk -rawdisk \\.\PhysicalDrive#
```

---

**EDIT:**

---

As per @GeraintJones' advice, I opened disk management in windows and got the following:

[image]

When no drive is selected, clicking on `Action > CreateVHD` results in the following dialog box:

[image]

**Note that the CentOS 7 component of the hard drive is located in the 4 partitions shown in the left part of Disk 1.**  (The detached disk 1 was extracted from a dead dual boot machine, and the windows portion of that old machine is located in the H: and I: drives shown at left.)

Also note that the CentOS 7 VM in the new computer cannot see the external drive.  I have done some work looking for it, and I think it would be a lot faster not to try to get the VirtualBox VM to do this.

**So how do I create a VHD for the CentOS portions of Disk 1 which are shown at right in the print screen above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways.

In disk manager in Windows you should be able to select the disk and choose "Create VHD" then you can import that to VirtualBox.

Or my preference would be to allocate a new VMDK that's slightly larger than the physical drive on your CentOS VM then use `dd` to clone the drive in there over to the new VMDK device.

Then you can remove the VMDK from the VM, and attach it to the VM where you'll be using it.

To do this on your existing CentOS VM run `sudo fdisk -l` and record the output there should be a few items - one of which will be the USB HDD

Then in VirtualBox select the VM that has the USB/SATA disk attached and click "Settings" then on the storage tab you should click the icon with a floppy disk and a plus then select "Add Hard Disk" :

[image: Add Disk]

In the following dialog choose "Create new disk" then follow the wizard (Making sure the disk you create is bigger than the one your cloning

Once that is done in the CentOS VM's console run `sudo fdisk -l` again and there should be a new device listed that is now  and the original USB HDD is . You may have to reboot the VM for  to be listed.

To clone the disk do `dd if=<usb> of=<newdevice> bs=1M` 
for example `dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=1M`

Once thats complete shut down the VM and then return to the Storage tab in VirtualBox settings and note the Location (highlight the disk you added and its on the right pane) then click the floppy disk with the red minus. In explorer then move the VMDK where you want it. On the new VM you repeat the process above but when you add the new disk select "Choose existing disk"

Comment: Done - Hope it helps

Comment: I am going to mark this as accepted and +1.  However, the simpler answer was to simply add the vmdk as an additional hard drive to the virtual machine, and then to extract data from it on an as needed basis.  The actual solution was very simple and only took a few minutes, though researching all these possible approaches took many days.

Comment: You asked `How do I clone the contents of that disk partition so that I can create a virtual machine in VirtualBox that has all the same data that is in the detached hard drive?` which is what I was answering, not `How do I copy files out of the existing VMDK as needed` :)